# Twitter-bootstrap: How to check if the popover is already showing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have created a popover on a dropdown via data attributes:

```
<select id="timezone_dropdown" data-content="This is the timezone" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Time Zone">
```

And whenever I click on a link button, I would like to show the popover floating over the dropdown.

```
<a class="btn timezone_help" href="#">Help</a>
```

In javascript I have defined it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $('.timezone_help').click(show_timezone_help);     
})

function show_timezone_help(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('#timezone_dropdown').popover('show');
}
```

This does the job, however when I click again on the button, it still stays there. Is there a way to check if its already open and hide it instead within the function, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.popover('toggle')`:

```
function show_timezone_help(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('#timezone_dropdown').popover('toggle');
}​
```

And add the attribute `data-trigger="manual"` to your dropdown.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XkLpD/)**.

Comment: Sorry but there is a problem. Please go on your DEMO and click on Help. The popover appears. Click again on Help for it to disappear.  Now click on the dropdown. The popover appears again. Very confusing. What is causing this? +1 for your effort, but I have to un-answer this for now as it seems the `toggle` might be problematic. Thank you

Comment: @Kave: Hi, try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2UVP/. Note that I've also added the `data-trigger="manual"` to the HTML of your dropdown.

Comment: @merv: I've updated my answer. I actually had initially suggested `popover('toggle')`, but forgot the `data-trigger` part. Still, I wouldn't say *highly* inefficient, this is a manual trigger... it's not running a million times per click. Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: Guys, I am still learning javascript/jquery.  If the code I have posted here is inefficient, please correct me, so I can learn. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kave: Not your code, but my previous version created an destroyed the popover object per click. My updated answer only creates the popover object once, and then hides/shows it. Note that the difference in performance here is almost completely negligible, but still, I'd stick with `popover('toggle')`, since it's simpler. The end result is the same.